# Attribute “titleTextStyle” has already been defined

Tags: android, gradle

I try to compile my project but I get these types of errors

`"Error: (2) Attribute" titleTextStyle "has Already Been defined"`

This is my Gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile project(':library')
compile project(':androidswitchbackport')
compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-4.2.0.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
//compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:0.97-incubator'
compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}
```

I have seen many questions and answers on this issue, but none has worked for me :(

Comment: Kenny, please see the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask questions. As far as your question goes, you're probably having a duplicate `titleTextStyle` attribute defined in your project. Search through your file system or in your IDE (find in all files) to find out where it comes from.

Comment: Post the logcat instead of the gradle file. It's not about the gradle, it's one of your xml files and the logcat will tell us which one.

Comment: 1) Make sure you're using the same version of support libs like `support-v4` and `appcompat-v7` *in all modules*. 2) Get rid of actionbarsherlock four years ago.

Comment: Can you be bothered to do a simple search with just the content of your error?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a problem with Gradle, or with your Gradle file.

Check your XML layout files and look for "`titleTextStyle`" (most likely in a TextView or some other widget). You most likely have a duplicate.

Comment: The issue is not that the attribute is *used* multiple times but that it's *defined* multiple times.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec true. Sorry for mistake.